# What is the difference between react-native install vs npm install?

Tags: facebook, reactjs, npm, react-native

I am new to React Native and have seen several blog posts/tutorials use react-native install or npm install for the dependencies. What is the difference and what are the advantages/disadvantages between both methods?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`react-native install xxx` is used to install a react native dependency which should be linked afterwards.
You need to link only native iOS/Android dependencies.

The same thing can be achieved by running `npm install xxx` and afterwards `react-native link xxx` to link the library

If you just want to install a JS only lib, you can just use `npm install`